# How to setup background image on Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, mintty

I am looking for a way to setup a background image on Cygwin. In the options of Cygwin shell Mintty there is no settings available to setup background image. 
Is there any other way to setup background image?

Answer (score 2):

#### How do I set a background image in mintty?

It is currently not possible.

There is an open enhancment request for this:

> [image]

Source [Mintty Issues](https://code.google.com/p/mintty/issues/list)

Answer (score 2):

This has been added in mintty 2.9.4 ([docs](https://github.com/mintty/mintty/wiki/Tips#background-image)).

Example in mintty config (for me, using WSL, this file is located at `%APPDATA%/wsltty/config`):

`Background=C:\Users\myself\Pictures\MyBackground.png,40`

This adds a background image with an opacity of 40%.

Comment: Works for me using Cygwin's mintty — with either slashes or backslashes in the file path.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the options, it doesn't look like you can change the background to something other than a single colour.

There is an option within the settings to change the transparency (so you can make it similar to the terminal in Linux Mint).

Right-Click on the title bar for the console, click Options.  Under the 'Looks' option, there is a 'Transparency' section, just select a level of transparency there.
Additionally, to make the background a slightly different colour, just click the 'Background' button and select a new colour.

HTH

Comment: This answer may have been correct when written in 2015, but Warlike Chimpanzee's answer works for me.